# How can I diagnose a problem with my CS50 code?

Tags: c, logic, cs50

I'm doing the CS50 course and I had this exercise in which I have to print a pyramid with # that looks something like this in C language using the height between 1 and 8 (include) chosen by the user:

```
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

But my code isn't working and I don't want to go to ChatGPT.

I am keen to only get a hint, so I can solve the problem myself.

Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    // Recebe uma altura do usuário entre 1 e 8;
    int h;
    do
    {
        h = get_int("Altura: ");
    }
    while (h < 1 || h > 8);

    // acrescenta uma quebra de linha até que atinja a altura
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
         // acrescenta uma # de acordo com a quantidade de quebra de linha
         for (int b = 0; b <= i; b++)
         {
             for (int j = h - 1; j > i; j--)
             {
                 printf(" ");
             }

             printf("#");
         }

         printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I did the first pyramid that looks like this:

```
      #
      ##
      ###
      ####
      #####
```

And I know how to do the reverse, because to have the right pyramid I need to replace theses # for blank space, then it'll seems like:

```
  *****
   ****
    ***
     **
      *
```

So I know I need to make a mix of these two then I can get the right pyramid, but when I mix them, it doesn't work.

```
  ****#
  ***##
  **###
  *####
  #####
```

Here is the output of my code:

[image: Here is the output of my code]

Comment: Please use the title to convey the *technical* problem you're having. It's not clear what you're getting as output vs. what you're expecting.

Comment: My code don't have any error of sintaxe. I edited my post and i put my output. Thank you.

Comment: *And i know how to do the reverse...* - so take that code, and instead of printing newlines, print `#` + newline. Then adjust numbers.

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of text, post text as text.

Comment: When you figure it out you can post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @pmacfarlane oh, thank you! i didn't knew that i could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is get the int j loop, take out of the b loop and put him inside of the first loop. Also put the initialization as "h - 1".

Here is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Recebe uma altura do usuário entre 1 e 8;
    int h;
    do
    {
        h = get_int("Altura: ");
    }
    while (h < 1 || h > 8);

    // acrescenta uma quebra de linha até que atinja a altura
    for (int i = 0; i <= h; i++)
    {
        // acrescenta uma # de acordo com a quantidade de quebra de linha
        for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");

        // insere os * de acordo com a quantidade de # em cada linha
        for (int j = h - 1; j > i; j--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code first prints some `*`, then one `#`; then, before printing the second `#` in a line, it prints some `*` again. That is because the loop for the `*` is nested inside the loop for the `#`.

Comment: Ohhh, thank you! I took the loop * and put him inside of the first for and it got me closer of what i want!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try putting another inner loop to print #

Comment: Can you please be more specific?